# Voltage divider equation except for capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Is there an easy way to find \$v_{out}\$with a handy voltage divider equation but for capacitors? If so, can you help me derive it?

I want to use it on this circuit:

[image]

Comment: Hi Melanie, it depends on the frequency and amplitude of the current applied by I_s. The idea of an voltage divider can still be applied, but you will be working with complex impedances instead of real resistances.

Answer (score 3):

I seriously apologize for the horrible formatting but I don't know LaTex OR MathJax and I have to leave town in the morning.

You could solve this using voltage and current divider equations, but I find it easier to just consider the current flows. Let \$I_1, I_2, I_3\$ and \$I_4\$ denote the current through \$C_1, C_2,\$ etc., and let \$V_1, V_2,\$ etc., denote the voltage across the corresponding capacitors.  Also recall that \$V = IZ\$, where \$Z = 1/sC\$ for a capacitor in the Laplace domain.

Notice that \$I_s = I_1 = I_2+I_3 = I_2+I_4\$, since \$I_3 = I_4\$.

Now \$V_2 = V_3 + V_4\$ , so 
$$
\frac{I_2}{sC_2} = \frac{I_3}{sC_3} + \frac{I_4}{sC_4}
$$

but \$I_3 = I_4\$, so
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{I_2}{sC_2} &= \frac{I_4}{sC_3} + \frac{I_4}{sC_4} \\
&= \frac{I_4}{s}\left(\frac{1}{C_3} + \frac{1}{C_4}\right)\\
&= \frac{I_4}{s}\frac{C_4+C_3}{C_3C_4}= I_4\frac{C_3+C_4}{sC_3C_4}
\end{split}
$$
and 
$$
I_2 = I_4\frac{C_2(C_3+C_4)}{(C_3C_4)}
$$
Now 
$$
\begin{split}
I_s & = I_4 + I_2\\
   & = I_4 + I_4\frac{C_2(C_3+C_4)}{C_3C_4}\\
   & = I_4\left\{1 + \frac{C_2(C_3+C_4)}{C_3C_4}\right\}\\
   & = I_4\frac{C_3C_4 + C_2(C_3+C_4)}{C_3C_4}
\end{split}
$$
so
$$
I_4 = I_s\frac{C_3C_4}{C_3C_4 + C_2(C_3+C_4)}
$$
Now 
$$
V_\mathrm{out} = V_4 = \frac{I_4}{sC_4}, 
$$
so
$$
\begin{split}
V_\mathrm{out} &= I_s\frac{C_3C_4[C_3C_4 + C_2(C_3+C_4)]}{sC_4}\\
& = I_s\frac{C_3}{s(C_3C_4 + C_2C_3 + C_2C_4)} = \frac{I_s}{sC}
\end{split}
$$
where
$$
C = \frac{C_2C_3 + C_2C_4 + C_3C_4}{C_3}
$$
Note that in the time domain, \$V_\mathrm{out}(t)\$ is \$1/C\$ times the integral of \$I_s(t)\$, so if \$I_s(t)\$ has any DC component, \$V_\mathrm{out}\$ will increase indefinitely until dielectric breakdown in one of the capacitors.

Hope I didn't make a mistake in all that, but you can see the general idea. :)

Comment: Thanks for reformatting it, Daniele! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the voltage \$V\$  across \$C_2\$, which is also the voltage \$V\$ across the series combination of  \$C_3 \$ and \$C_4\$, Total charge stored by the series combination of \$C_3 \$ and \$C_4\$ will be:
$$Q_T=C_{eq}V=\frac{C_3C_4}{(C_3+C_4)}V$$
Both \$C_3\$ and \$C_4\$ store the same charge \$Q_T\$ as well as they are in series, ie.,:
$$Q_T=C_3V_3 =C_4V_{out}=\frac{C_3C_4}{(C_3+C_4)}V$$
$$\implies V_{out}=\frac{C_3}{(C_3+C_4)}V$$
To find \$V\$, you can employ the same idea by combining parallel-series combination of \$C_2, C_3,C_4\$ into one equivalent capacitor in series with \$C_1\$ and form an expression with input voltage.

Comment: As an aside, these formulas work for ideal capacitors but in the real world we must consider the leakage current through the capacitors as well. For big electrolytic capacitors at dc you really can't use these formulas at all.

Comment: Yea ...........